# If $a(n) + b(n) \in \Omega(p(n))$, then $a(n) \in \Omega(p(n)) \vee b(n)\in \Omega(p(n))$.

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics, proof-explanation

If $a(n) + b(n) \in \Omega(p(n))$, then $a(n) \in \Omega(p(n)) \vee b(n)\in \Omega(p(n))$.

I believe this statement to be false. Am I wrong? What functions should I use to show a disproof or a proof?

Comment: Is this Hardy-Littlewood $\Omega$ or Knuth $\Omega$?

Comment: Knuth, I believe. $f(n) \in \Omega(g(n))$: $\exists c_1, n_0 \in \mathbb{R^{\leq 0}}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n > n_0 \Rightarrow c_1 \cdot g(n) \leq f(n)$.

Comment: Since the only constraint we have is on $a+b,$ an easy way to violate the statement is to make both $a$ and $b$ highly variable with misaligned peaks. So, for instance, $a(n) = p(n) \mathbf{1}\{n \textrm{ is even} \}, b(n) = p(n) \mathbf{1}\{n \textrm{ is odd} \}$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function. Clearly $\lim\inf \frac{a(n)}{p(n)}= 0$ because $a/p = 0$ infinitely often, and the same for $b$.

Note on the other hand that the closely related statement $\exists C \forall n \textrm{ large enough}: a(n) > Cp(n) \vee b(n) > Cp(n)$ is true.